# Problem passing a converted CSV dictionary file in a Post request

Tags: python, json, csv, post, python-requests

Am having a problem passing a CSV file that has been converted to a `dict` file in a post request as a payload in Python. But when I print the payload I got the expected dictionary output but when I now pass the payload as data I got an error that `Error: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"`.

What does this mean . Below is a snapshot of my code:

```
import requests, json, csv
url = "https://192.168.15.4/web_api/v1.6.1/login"
payload= "{\r\n  \"user\" : \"admin\",\r\n  \"password\" : \"****\"\r\n}"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)
response_dict = json.loads(response.text)
session_id = response_dict['sid']
print(response_dict['sid'])

url = "https://192.168.15.4/web_api/v1.6.1/publish"
payload="{ }"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-chkp-sid': session_id
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)
data = open("C:/Users/OdedinaP/Python_Learning/Add-Multi-Host/add_mutli_host.csv")
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(data)
csv_data = list(csv_reader)[0:20]
csvJson_data = json.dumps(csv_data)
for row in csv_data:
    csvJson_data = {json.dumps(csv_data)}
    payload = (csv_data)

headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'X-chkp-sid': session_id
}
#print(payload)
url = "https://192.168.15.4/web_api/v1.6.1/add-host"
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)
print(response.text)
```

When I comment out the last two lines and uncomment the `print(payload)` I got the expected output for the payload below:

```
[{'name': 'PC1', 'ip-address': '192.168.10.1', 'color': 'Yellow'},
 {'name': 'PC2', 'ip-address': '192.168.10.2', 'color': 'Yellow'},
 {'name': 'PC3', 'ip-address': '192.168.10.3', 'color': 'Yellow'},
 {'name': 'PC4', 'ip-address': '192.168.10.4', 'color': 'Yellow'},
 {'name': 'PC5', 'ip-address': '192.168.10.5', 'color': 'Yellow'},
 {'name': 'PC6', 'ip-address': '192.168.10.6', 'color': 'Yellow'},
 {'name': 'PC7', 'ip-address': '192.168.10.7', 'color': 'Yellow'},
 {'name': 'PC8', 'ip-address': '192.168.10.8', 'color': 'Yellow'},
 {'name': 'PC9', 'ip-address': '192.168.10.9', 'color': 'Yellow'},
 {'name': 'PC10', 'ip-address': '192.168.10.10', 'color': 'Yellow'},
 {'name': 'PC11', 'ip-address': '192.168.10.11', 'color': 'Yellow'},
 {'name': 'PC12', 'ip-address': '192.168.10.12', 'color': 'Yellow'},
 {'name': 'PC13', 'ip-address': '192.168.10.13', 'color': 'Yellow'},
 {'name': 'PC14', 'ip-address': '192.168.10.14', 'color': 'Yellow'},
 {'name': 'PC15', 'ip-address': '192.168.10.15', 'color': 'Yellow'},
 {'name': 'PC16', 'ip-address': '192.168.10.16', 'color': 'Yellow'},
 {'name': 'PC17', 'ip-address': '192.168.10.17', 'color': 'Yellow'},
 {'name': 'PC18', 'ip-address': '192.168.10.18', 'color': 'Yellow'},
 {'name': 'PC19', 'ip-address': '192.168.10.19', 'color': 'Yellow'},
 {'name': 'PC20', 'ip-address': '192.168.10.20', 'color': 'Yellow'}]
```

Comment: Please include the entire traceback for the error, not just the last line, in your question so we can tell what line of code is causing it.

Comment: Do you want to send request for each line of payload? Now it's not in loop

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "add_multi_host.py", line 33, in <module>
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)

Comment: File "C:\Users\OdedinaP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\OdedinaP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 516, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)

Comment: File "C:\Users\OdedinaP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 449, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "C:\Users\OdedinaP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 317, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
  File "C:\Users\OdedinaP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 508, in prepare_body
    body = self._encode_params(data)

Comment: File "C:\Users\OdedinaP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 97, in _encode_params
    for k, vs in to_key_val_list(data):
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Thanks Martineau that is all the traceback error

Comment: Yes I want to send the request for each line of payload

Comment: Hi,I have slightly modify my code to have my payload output as a Jason format output but now i am getting a different error TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: below is the new code adjustment. Any thought would be appreciated

Comment: import requests, json, csv
url = "https://192.168.15.4/web_api/v1.6.1/login"
payload= "{\r\n  \"user\" : \"admin\",\r\n  \"password\" : \"trash80\"\r\n}"
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'

Comment: }
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)
response_dict = json.loads(response.text)
session_id = response_dict['sid']
print(response_dict['sid'])

url = "https://192.168.15.4/web_api/v1.6.1/publish"
payload="{ }"
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'X-chkp-sid': session_id
}

Comment: response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)
#data = open("C:/Users/OdedinaP/Python_Learning/Add-Multi-Host/add_mutli_host.csv", 'rb')

Comment: with open("C:/Users/OdedinaP/Python_Learning/Add-Multi-Host/add_mutli_host.csv", 'r') as data:
       csv_reader = csv.DictReader(data)
       csv_data = list(csv_reader)
       csvJson_data = json.dumps(csv_data)
       csvJson_data = json.dumps(csv_data)
       for row in csvJson_data:
           csvJson_data = {json.dumps(csv_data)}
           payload = (csvJson_data)

Comment: headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-chkp-sid': session_id
}
print(payload)
url = "https://192.168.15.4/web_api/v1.6.1/add-host"
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)
print(response.text)

Comment: And my new payload output is :

Comment: {'[{"name": "PC1", "ip-address": "192.168.10.1", "color": "Yellow"}, {"name": "PC2", "ip-address": "192.168.10.2", "color": "Yellow"}, {"name": "PC3", "ip-address": "192.168.10.3", "color": "Yellow"}, {"name": "PC4", "ip-address": "192.168.10.4", "color": "Yellow"}, {"name": "PC5", "ip-address": "192.168.10.5", "color": "Yellow"}, {"name": "PC6", "ip-address": "192.168.10.6", "color": "Yellow"}, {"name": "PC7", "ip-address": "192.168.10.7", "color": "Yellow"}, {"name": "PC8", "ip-address": "192.168.10.8", "color": "Yellow"}, {"name": "PC9", "ip-address": "192.168.10.9", "color": "Yellow"}

Comment: {"name": "PC10", "ip-address": "192.168.10.10", "color": "Yellow"}, {"name": "PC11", "ip-address": "192.168.10.11", "color": "Yellow"}, {"name": "PC12", "ip-address": "192.168.10.12", "color": "Yellow"}, {"name": "PC13", "ip-address": "192.168.10.13", "color": "Yellow"}, {"name": "PC14", "ip-address": "192.168.10.14", "color": "Yellow"},

Comment: {"name": "PC15", "ip-address": "192.168.10.15", "color": "Yellow"}, {"name": "PC16", "ip-address": "192.168.10.16", "color": "Yellow"}, {"name": "PC17", "ip-address": "192.168.10.17", "color": "Yellow"}, {"name": "PC18", "ip-address": "192.168.10.18", "color": "Yellow"}, {"name": "PC19", "ip-address": "192.168.10.19", "color": "Yellow"}, {"name": "PC20", "ip-address": "192.168.10.20", "color": "Yellow"}]'}